# is there a way to access a non-global shadowed variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, global

I'm currently learning javascript scope and was just wondering whether it is possible to access a non-global shadowed variable in javascript? i.e. in the example below, the variable `a` that equal to 10 in the `aFunc` function

```
var a = 1;
function aFunc(){
    var a = 10;
    function innerFunc(){
        var a = 100;
        console.log("innerFunc a = " + a);
        console.log("is it possible to access outer function's a variable?");
        console.log("global a = " + window.a);
    }
    innerFunc();
}
aFunc();
```

ps - I understand naming your variables with the same name is very bad practice, but I guess I asked this question out of curiosity

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot do this with Javascript at least. There is no way that you can access it since you have intentionally shadowed it (accept it as a feature ;)). Javascript doesn't have a mechanism to access variables in lexical scope (one step up).

Comment: hi Suresh, thanks for the helping out!. I was just wondering, do you happen to know  why javascript doesn't provide this feature? In other words, what are the reasons for this design? (I have java background and in java we can access shadowed variable many levels up).

Comment: @CaptainAmerica Because that is how JS works and `The word "lexical" refers to the fact that lexical scoping uses the location where a variable is declared within the source code to determine where that variable is available.` Since you have shadowed that will have the latest value init.

Comment: @CaptainAmerica BTW, Java doesn't have nested functions. You mean inner classes ? or anonymous inner classes ?

Comment: oh yes, inner classes is what I meant. sorry I didn't make myself clear

Comment: @CaptainAmerica Yeah, but we have to understand the fact that we shouldn't compare both. Each have it's unique style of functionality and rule set.